# R ggplot: grouped boxplot using group-variable in facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to have a grouped boxplot. The problem is that the y-variable
has large differnces between the first *n* factor levels and the second *m* factor levels.
Three solutions seem possible:

1. Create two seperate graphs and combine them with a shared legend.
2. Create two different y-axes in one graph
3. Use facet grid.

Since 1. and 2. appear to be cumbersome, I thought I'd give 3. a shot.
The problem is, that in each subplot all factor level show up.
The example below illustrates the issue.

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$carb.bin <- mtcars$carb > 2
mtcars$hp[mtcars$carb > 2] <- 10*mtcars$hp[mtcars$carb > 2]

ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb, hp)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(carb))) +
facet_wrap(carb.bin~ ., scales = "free")
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Trying facet_wrap(~carb.bin, scales = "free") works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for facet_wrap() is confusing ggplot2 (well, me anyway ;-) )
From ?facet_wrap:

> facets: Either a formula or character vector. Use either a one sided
>             formula, ‘~a + b’, or a character vector, ‘c("a", "b")’.

I get

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb, hp)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(carb))) + 
facet_wrap(carb.bin~., scales = "free")
#Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
 # At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
#and no plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb, hp)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(carb))) +
facet_wrap(~carb.bin, scales = "free")

#produces desired plot, add arg ncol=1 to have one facet above the other
```

[image]

Note the syntax/order of terms for your facet_wrap() formula.